# Can Windows handle multiple monitors drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors

At work I have 2 monitors connected to my PC. They're the same manufacturer and model. Windows 10 handles this fine.

At home I only have 1 monitor on a Windows 10 Professional PC. But if I were to get another monitor, very likely it wouldn't be the same make/model. Can Windows handle device drivers from 2 manufacturers for 2 monitors connected to the machine? Or do you have to use the generic device driver from Microsoft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monitors don't really require drivers, and even when they do, there's no restrictions that all the drivers must be for the same make/model of monitor.

So the make/model of the monitor won't matter as long as it's compatible with your video adapter's output type.

Perhaps check out this existing related SU question:

- [Is there any point in installing a monitor driver?](https://superuser.com/questions/42502/is-there-any-point-in-installing-a-monitor-driver)

Comment: Thank you @Techie007. And thanks for the link. I've been around PC long enough so I thought you'd always have to download the manufacturer's drivers. Seems like I'm wrong about that; that it depends more upon the machine's video card/driver.