# LG monitor driver installed but still poor quality and does not pivot

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors, lg-monitor

I just bought a [LG 24BK550Y](http://www.lg.com/us/business/commercial-display/it-products/desktop-monitors/lg-24BK550Y-B) pivotable monitor, it works but:

- Display quality is very poor. As if brushed on, not sharp at all.
- Turning the screen does not pivot the view

**What I've done so far**

1. I've installed the driver.
2. I've installed onScreen Control

Resolution is the recommended 1920x1080. Windows insists on doing automatic scaling, but that's at 100% so I guess that's fine.

It's connected using HDMI.

**Installing the driver**

I'm using the web pages provided on the accompanied CD, when downloading the setup.exe and running, it complains that no INF can be found:

[image]

And it fails.

Running the setup directly from CD does provide me with the correct screen:

[image]

And the message that it worked:

[image]

***However***

If I go to control panel / hardware, I saw that the monitor still only had a general PNP screen driver installed.

Using the update driver functionality associated with it, I got it to be like this:

[image]
[image]

I've restarted and did a full shutdown numerous times now, the screen quality is still poor (as if painted on, not realistic).

**I've installed onScreen Control**

I don't know if this is what enables pivoting the screen, but it doesn't happen at any rate.

> What should I do to get this working?

An example of what I mean by "painted on":

[image]

This probably isn't exactly what's happening, but it's pretty close. It's like my main screen is the left side, realistic, detailed and sharp, the new screen I'm talking about is like the right side.

Comment: I think the driver is still not installed, despite appearences, the usb drives don't work either.

Answer (score 1):

### Image quality

Your screenshots don't actually show what driver is in use, that would be the `Sturrprogramma` tab I believe, but as the display name is shown, I would believe that the driver is correctly installed. Either way, it won't make a difference, see: https://superuser.com/a/42517/379161

You may have to go into more detail about the quality of the image, "brushed on" is not very clear as to what you mean.

I would suggest using a digital connection if you were using a VGA cable, but it appears that you are using a HDMI cable for the connection.

What about monitor settings (contrast, exposure, colour correction, sharpness)?  New monitors do some image processing on-board, and this may be the cause of the issue?

### Screen orientation

From the LG site:

[image]

> STAND
> Base Detachable  Yes
>  Tilt (Angle)    -5° ~ 35°
> Height range   130mm
> Down Height    70mm
> Pivot   Yes (Bi-directional, 90°)
> Mini PC Bracket Ready  Yes

The stand pivots, the monitor is just attached to the stand.  (you can see this in the image.  The part of the stand attached to the rear of the monitor is a different colour to the rear of the monitor.

There are no electrical connections in there, no switches to determine orientation.  To rotate the display, you need to rotate the monitor, and tell the OS to use the display in its rotated orientation.  This can be done in the OS settings or graphics card driver settings.  Some drivers have hotkeys for this; intel drivers use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd>+(<kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>) to select orientation.

OSC allows you to control PIP or splitscreen on your monitor.  It doesn't detect orientation. (I don't have it, it may also allow rotation to be set, telling the OS which orientation to use, but it won't be automatic.)

Comment: I've added an example of what I mean by painted on (or as close as I could find).

Comment: would a photo be clearer enough?  It does seem like it could be on on-monitor setting.  Do you have another device you can test with? Try attaching that to the screen and see if you get a similar problem.

Comment: I tried photos first, but the difference is not really visible.

Answer (score 0):

I just recognise that you wrote you bought "LG 24BK55" (resolution 1920x1200) but the driver tells "BK550" which indeed has just what you reported: "Resolution is the recommended 1920x1080".
So maybe you can investigate this mismatch?

Comment: Can you give more explanation, your answer is like a comment

Answer (score -1):

The LG 24BK55 has **WUXGA** native resolution (1920 * **1200** pixel) and it seems that a driver for model 24BK55**0** is installed which is a different model and just has **Full-HD** native resolution (1920 * **1080** pixel).
So maybe you should check if the driver is suitable to your TFT model, for me it seems that TFT hardware and driver are not matching.

Some background information:
I want to buy a new TFT and I am very interested in 24BK55 type, so I studied a lot of information (a lot means so far available in the www) regarding this and other models.
Hence, I do not yet have one and I have never installed a LG driver and I am not using Win10, so I have no own experience with this software.

Bye, Andreas